# Linked list of template type with the next pointer being a different specialization

Tags: c++, templates, linked-list

I would liked to have a class template with a single type parameter, and inside the class hold a pointer to the next class in the linked-list, but allow that class to potentially be of a different type (in this example the different type is a specialization.)

I tried this code:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Banana
{
    public:
        void function(T parameter); // illustrates class methods/members only concerned with single type T

        Banana<U>* next;
}
```

The compiler gives error:

> 'Banana':too few template arguments.

Comment: Inherit `Banana<??>` from a non-template base, and use a pointer to it. Or make `Banana` non-template and store a `std::variant` inside (or store a `std::unique_ptr` to a polymorphic class).

Comment: Maybe using a non-template base class. It is called type erasure

Comment: What would you do with an element of such a list? To make things abundantly clear, replace `Banana` with `std::vector`. You want a list of vectors, without saying vectors of *what*. What can you do with a vector of nobody-knows-what?

Comment: @ n. m. could be an AI - What would you do with an element of such a list?

I want to build a signal processing chain. Each block will have an input type and an output type. Each block will do its think and when done, call the next block.

The first block might take integers from the ADC and convert to floating point, the next block might aggregate and down sample so go from floats to double.

I would like to experiment with different precision types, hence use templates.

Comment: Let's try again. You have `void function(T parameter)` How do you plan to call this function if your object is *just* a `Banana` and `T` is nowhere to be seen?

Comment: @ n. m. could be an AI.

Take a look at my answer below - where in a much simplified code, I achieve what I am aiming to do.

Each block has an Apply function. It takes as an input a parameter of type T. its output is of type U, which is the type the next blocks' apply function takes as an input.

I got something working below. It half uses templates. I am surprised its so hard (perhaps impossible) by fully using templates.

Answer (score 2):

I gather you want to do this statically. One way to do this is to specify a succession order. In the example below I have composed the type, but this will obviously not work if you have loops in your succession order. In that case, use a `std::unique_ptr` instead.

```
template <typename V>
struct SuccessorMaker { using type = V; };

template <typename> struct Successor : SuccessorMaker<void> {}; // end
// specify succession order here
template <> struct Successor<int> : SuccessorMaker<float> {};
template <> struct Successor<float> : SuccessorMaker<short> {};

template <typename T>
struct Banana {
  void function(T);
  Banana<typename Successor<T>::type> next;
};
template <> struct Banana<void> {}; // end of list

int main() {
    Banana<int> banana;
    banana.function(1);
    banana.next.function(2.f);
}
```

([demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dbdz1zEMY))

You can of course also do this with polymorphism by having a common base class. This would be just a regular list.

---

Edit: Here's a way to do it dynamically at runtime. It is a bit more cumbersome to instantiate but it allows you the flexibility to have arbitrary lists. See the updated link to the demo above.

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct CherryTree {
  template <typename T>
  struct Cherry {
    void function(T);
    template <typename U>
    auto& setNext() {
        auto ptr = std::make_unique<Cherry<T>>();
        auto const res = ptr.get();
        next = std::move(ptr);
        return *res;
    }
    std::variant<std::unique_ptr<Cherry<Ts>>...> next;
  };
};

int main() {
    using Tree = CherryTree<int,float,short>;
    Tree::Cherry<int> cherry;
    cherry.function(1);

    //cherry.next = std::make_unique<Tree::Cherry<float>>();
    auto& next = cherry.setNext<float>();
    next.function(2.f); // call after reset
    std::visit([](auto& n) {n->function(3.f);}, cherry.next); // regular call
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is a step forward for sure.

Can I check my understanding. This specifically sets what the rule is between two blocks.
When you have a int Banana, you must follow with a float Banana. This would not allow int Banana followed by a float Banana, and then an int Banana followed by a short Banana later in the list? I guess this is what you mean by 'loops in your succession order'

Comment: @user202474 - a more generic way to handle this would be to have the next pointer as the first member of a class | struct, followed by the type of class | struct.

Comment: @rcgldr. Could you provide an example please?

Comment: @user202474 If you want a more complex structure, perhaps consider just using a large `std::tuple`?

Comment: @user202474 See updated answer. It provides a `Cherry` type that allows you dynamic lists.

Comment: @user202474 - your alternate approach is a similar idea, the first member is the next pointer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your own answer, it seems to me that you want a pipeline processing. If it's not the case, feel free to comment and I'll remove this answer.

If you don't insist on using classes, here's a free-function approach. In order to support different pipelines, I introduced a `Pipeline` enum.

The `apply()` functions in the `detail` namespace do the conversion/processing, the `pipeline()` function is responsible for the iteration.

```cpp
enum class Pipeline
{
    A,
    B,
    C
};

namespace detail
{
    template <Pipeline id, typename Input, typename Output>
    Output apply(Input);
    
    template <>
    float apply<Pipeline::A, int, float>(int i)
    {
        return i;
    }

    template <>
    std::string apply<Pipeline::A, float, std::string>(float f)
    {
        return std::to_string(f);
    }
}


template <Pipeline id, typename Input, typename Output, typename... Ts>
auto pipeline(Input input)
{
    Output output = detail::apply<id, Input, Output>(input);
    
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) > 0)
    {
        return pipeline<id, Output, Ts...>(output);
    }
    else
    {
        return output;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << pipeline<Pipeline::A, int, float, std::string>(64) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
64.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to chain functions, you may like something like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <string>

template <typename A, typename B>
struct Func
{
    Func(std::function<A(B)> func) : func(func) {};
    A operator()(B b) const { return func(b); }

    std::function<A(B)> func;
};

template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
Func<A,C> operator|(Func<A,B> ab, Func<B,C> bc)
{
    return Func<A,C>([ab,bc](C c)->A{return ab(bc(c)); });
}

int main()
{
    Func<int, double> f ([](double d) { return (int) d; });
    Func<std::string, int> g ([](int i) { return std::to_string(i); });
    Func<int, std::string> h ([](std::string s) { return std::stoi(s); });

    auto chain = h | g | f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Bitmask and others.

I have come up with an alternative approach.

I have a non-template base class and for it I declare a virtual function for all types I will use. I define empty functions for all these types, since I don't use them. I instead use a derived class, which has a base class pointer to the next block.

The derived block is templated by its type and its neighbours type. I override the base function for its type.

The downsides are having to explicitly declare the needed types in the base class, and explicitly give an empty implementation. For my purposes this is too bad.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

#include<string>

class BaseBlock
{
    public:

        BaseBlock* next;

        virtual void Apply(char sample);
        virtual void Apply(int sample);
        virtual void Apply(float sample);
        virtual void Apply(double sample);
        virtual void Apply(short sample);
        virtual void Apply(std::string sample);
};


template <typename T, typename U>
class DerivedBlock : public BaseBlock
{
    public:

        void Apply(T sample);
};


template <typename T, typename U>
void::DerivedBlock<T, U>::Apply(T sample)
{
    std::cout << "DerivedBlock::Apply - typeid: " << typeid(sample).name() << "   value: " << sample << std::endl << std::endl;

    if (next != 0)
    {
        next->Apply((U)sample);
    }
}


template <>
void::DerivedBlock<short, std::string>::Apply(short sample)
{
    std::cout << "DerivedBlock::Apply - typeid: " << typeid(sample).name() << "   value: " << sample << std::endl << std::endl;

    if (next != 0)
    {
        next->Apply(std::to_string(sample));
    }
}

template <>
void::DerivedBlock<std::string, int>::Apply(std::string sample)
{
    std::cout << "DerivedBlock::Apply - typeid: " << typeid(sample).name() << "   value: " << sample << std::endl << std::endl;

    if (next != 0)
    {
        next->Apply(std::stoi(sample));
    }
}

int main()
{

    DerivedBlock<int, float> db_int_float;
    DerivedBlock<float, char> db_float_char;
    DerivedBlock<char, int> db_char_int;
    DerivedBlock<int, double> db_int_double;
    DerivedBlock<double, short> db_double_short;
    DerivedBlock<short, std::string> db_short_stdString;
    DerivedBlock<std::string, int> db_stdString_int;

    db_int_float.next = &db_float_char;
    db_float_char.next = &db_char_int;
    db_char_int.next = &db_int_double;
    db_int_double.next = &db_double_short;
    db_double_short.next = &db_short_stdString;
    db_short_stdString.next = &db_stdString_int;
    db_stdString_int.next = 0; // End of list

    db_int_float.Apply(83U);

    return 0;
}


void BaseBlock::Apply(char sample) {};
void BaseBlock::Apply(int sample) {};
void BaseBlock::Apply(float sample) {};
void BaseBlock::Apply(double sample) {};
void BaseBlock::Apply(short sample) {};
void BaseBlock::Apply(std::string sample) {};
```

Produces:

[image]

Comment: If you want to take anything from my answer let it be using `std::unique_ptr` instead of a raw pointer.